ArcGIS REST API returns no results when resultRecordCount parameter is added
I have a mapservice which is queried by VertiGIS Studio Web which returns no results. When I reproduce the query the service returns a result when I leave the parameter resultRecordCount empty. When fired from VSW the value is 500.
Other mapservices work fine with the resultRecordCount parameter. I published a different service from the same source but this did not solve the problem.
The source is a 2D point featureclass in SDE. What could cause this and how to solve it?
=== update 2024-09-30 ===
A teammember pointed out I should update this post with the complete request.
This works:
https://domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Federated/InfraViewer/MapServer/64/query

f=pbf&
geometry=<geometry>&
where=1%3D1&
outFields=<outFields>&
spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&
geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&
inSR=28992&
outSR=28992&
token=<token>

This does not:
https://domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Federated/InfraViewer/MapServer/64/query

f=pbf&
geometry=<geometry>&
resultRecordCount=500&
where=1%3D1&
outFields=<outFields>&
spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&
geometryType=esriGeometryPolygon&
inSR=28992&
outSR=28992&
token=<token>

With the only difference is the resultRecordCount=500 parameter.

According to Query (Feature Service/Layer) | ArcGIS REST APIs | ArcGIS Developers, "This parameter only applies if supportsPagination is true."  Are you sure pagination is supported on the service?

Good point. I doublechecked but this service supports Pagination.

I found older records which do work fine. (This is a featureclass with points added over time.) I did recalculate the extents and rebuild the spatial index, but this did not change anything. I'll try and republish the service...

You mention "older records which do work fine," do you mean other records in the same service?  If so, what is different with the query criteria for when it works and doesn't work?

Different location, it is an intersect with a polygon, which represents an identify.

What I have tried and did not work:

Recalculate Extents on featureclass.
Delete and create spatial index.
Overwrite the service.
Create a new service.

The only thing which worked:

Recreate the featureclass in SDE with appendix _new.
Migrate the data from original to new.
Recalculate Extents on new.
Rebuild spatial index on new.
Create field attributes on new.
Stop all services looking to the original featureclass.
Rename original featureclass with appendig _original.
Rename new featureclass removing appendix _new.

I really did not want to go this route but I needed to get the service working again.
